# Generate MSSQL database script using command line

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, command-line, backup

I have a database on server which i don't have RDP access. I need to create a backup of data, stored procedure and functions of the database on the server. I tried "generate script" but it fails saying there is some "Transport layer error" occurred.

Is there any way i can generate script of the database on server using command line or any other tool.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a login that you can use with ssms? rdp access is pretty much irrelevant anyway. if you have ssms login and that throws the error then any other solution is likely to do the same

Comment: Thanks. I have ssms login and i am able to login succesfully. The issue occurs when i try to generate the script. I am not able to either import data or generate script.

Comment: what happens if you try to create the script on something small and easy? same thing?

Comment: if a single table with small data, then it gets success.

Comment: in that case i have bad news for you, your problem in networking related.

Comment: Okay, but is there any other way like command prompt or something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64238/discussion-between-tristan-and-deeps).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can use xp_cmdshell. If yes backup database and copy bak file

USE master
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'copy c:\sqlbackup\DB.bak \server2\backups\', 
   NO_OUTPUT